# lookup a number and increment value in another cell within same row

Tags: vba

I would like to create a macro in excel that lets me increment the counts of a part whenever I press a command button.

Currently, my concept is to use vlookup to get the existing counts for that part using the following. However, it does not increment the actual counts value in the cell, which is what I want.  I suspect it's cos vlookup is only used to return a value within the cell, but the cell is not activated in the process for actual increment. Can someone please advise how I can correct it? I'm still new to vba. Thanks!!! :)

E.g. Vlookup finds C1value in Cell A5 of Sheets("Location"). It will automatically increment the value in Cell C5 by 1.

```
Sub FindAddTools()

Dim C1Qnty As Double

C1value = Sheets("Issue").Range("D11")

Sheets("Location").Activate

C1Qnty = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(C1value, Range("A:D"), 3, False)

C1Qnty = C1Qnty + 1

End Sub
```

ADD ON: an add-on to my original question. I was wondering if it is possible to do the same for an entire range?

E.g. C1value is now a range of Sheets("Issue").Range("D11:D20"). I want to find all values within this range in Sheets("Location") and increment their corresponding counts in Column C.

Is there a way to do this without repeating the same procedure for all cells of the range?
Thanks! :)

Comment: What cell should be incremented?

Comment: The value that I looked up for is in Column A, when I find that value, I want to increase the counts in Column C, same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my shot at it. If the value isn't matched nothing happens:

```
Sub FindAddTools()
Dim RangeToMatch As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim C1Value As Variant
Dim C1Row As Variant

Set RangeToMatch = Sheets("Issue").Range("D2:D11")
For Each cell In RangeToMatch
    C1Value = cell.Value
    With Sheets("Location")
        C1Row = Application.Match(C1Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(C1Row) Then
            .Range("C" & C1Row).Value = .Range("C" & C1Row).Value + 1
        End If
    End With
Next cell
End Sub
```

I edited it so that it cycles through a range of cells to match. That range is set to `D2:D11` above.

Comment: Thanks Doug! What if I would like to match an entire range in "Issue" and increment all the corresponding counts in "Location" Column C. Is it possible to do that as well?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think this should do it.

NB: you don't have to `Activate` worksheets to perform the functions referencing their cells/ranges.

```
Sub FindAddTools()
Dim shIssue as WOrksheet: Set shIssue = Sheets("Issue")
Dim shLoc as Worksheet: Set shLoc = Sheets("Location")
Dim allC1Values as Range
Dim C1Value as Variant 
Dim C1Qnty As Double
Dim foundRow as Long


Set allC1Values = shIssue.Range("D11:D100") '## Modify as needed.
For each C1Value in allC1Values.Cells

    C1Qnty = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(C1value, shLoc.Range("A:D"), 3, False)
    C1Qnty = C1Qnty + 1

    foundRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(c1Value,shLoc.Range("A:A"),False)
    shLoc.Range("C" & foundRow).Value = CqQnty
Next
End Sub
```

Be careful with this. You're immediately writing to the same cell you just "found" with the `VLOOKUP` function, so, obviously if you run this macro again, you're going to increment it again.  But, this may be the desired functionality, if so, no problem.

NOTE: There is no error trapping for if `C1Value` is **not** found in the `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` functions.

Comment: Thanks David! What if I would like to do the same an entire range in "Issue" and increment all the corresponding counts in "Location" Column C. Can you think of anyway to do it without having to repeat the procedure again for the other values?

Comment: Yes, that is easy enough to do. See my revision above. I have not tested it, but I am pretty sure it will work.